# jquery tabs in visualforce example not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, salesforce, visualforce

Hi i am writng a simple visualforce page source code is

```
<apex:page >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->

  <head>
   <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.UIJQuery1822, 'js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/> 
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css')}"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        $( "#tabset" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>
  <Title>Hello World</Title></head>
  <Body>
  <div id="tabset">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#panel1">Tab One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#panel2">Tab Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#panel3">Tab Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="panel1"> Hello World1</div>
  <div id="panel2">Hello World2</div>
  <div id="panel3">Hello World3 </div>

  </div>
  </Body>

</apex:page>
```

i am trying to create a set of three tabs but its showing an unordered list and three div element no tab,means jquery code is not working .can any one please tell me why it is not working,and give me the suggestion  that how to make it work?

Comment: Check whether JQuery UI Script is loaded in the page

Comment: yes it is loading correctly in page i saw view source and giving me
src="/resource/1354367419000/UIJQuery1822/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
tabs can be made with jquery-1.7.2.min.js or not?? beginner in jquery

Comment: JQuery file is necessary for performing some operation and whereas jquery ui is necessary for tabs please check the below link http://jqueryui.com /tabs/                                    Necessary files for tabs with jquery                 http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js                        http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: a comment only be voted i think i cant mark a comment as answer if there is a way please specify it

Comment: i have posted it in answer you can mark it as answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery file is necessary for performing some operation and whereas jquery ui is necessary for tabs please check the below link jqueryui.com /tabs/ Necessary files for tabs with jquery code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css